# What does “to take someone back” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I read that someone was advised to do the following regarding that person’s ex:

> Get her to take you back.

What does that mean?

Comment: Any dictionary is going to tell you what the phrasal verb ***to take (someone or something) back*** means. It doesn’t matter whether the thing being taken back is a library book or a girlfriend: this is still General Reference.

Comment: If you are an English-language learner, you might like to take a look at our sister-site, [ell.se]. That’s because that one there is a Q&A site **especially made for *learners***, while this one here is instead a Q&A site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.**

Answer (score 3):

It means "Do whatever you need to do so that she becomes (once more) your current lover (rather than your ex-lover)." Or put another way, "Do whatever you need to do to repair your relationship with her."

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out already, "get her to take you back" means advising you *to take some action so that your ex comes back to you in your relationship.*

Here's a usage of this phrase from this [ehow](http://www.ehow.com/how_7456846_her-back.html) link-

> **How to Get Her to Take You Back**
>
> By Kelly Smith, eHow Contributor

This is a summary(reasoning) of the title used above-

> You want her back, but you don't know where to start, and you may not
>   even know how you lost her in the first place. There are some surefire
>   ways to get her back, providing you didn't do anything unforgivable in
>   the first place. It takes more than just saying you're sorry or
>   begging for forgiveness. The average woman wants a better attempt at
>   winning her love back than a lame, "I'm sorry" or "I didn't mean it."
>   She wants action and follow-through to show her that she made the
>   right choice being with you in the first place.

Hope the meaning is clear to you now!